# In Electron, is the default session persistent?

Tags: session, cookies, electron

I'm using Electron (v1.2.7) and I need session cookies to persist between app restarts (for auth).

Is it possible? I know in Chrome when you set "Continue where you left off", the session is kept but not sure if this works the same in Electron.

As a workaround, I tried storing the session cookies also as non session cookies but it failed with a generic error.

Clarification: I'm not setting the session cookies they are set by other webpages during authentication.

Answer (score 5):

The default session is persistent, but if you set cookies using `session.defaultSession.cookies.set()` you must set the expiration date in order for the cookie to be persisted.

Comment: Our code is not the one setting the cookies, they are set by other web pages visited (during auth and on an iframe if it matters).

Comment: @AmitApple How are you shutting down your app, with `app.quit()` or `process.exit()`?

Comment: it shouldn't matter, I always want the session to be kept.

Comment: @AmitApple It matters because if the app is not shutdown cleanly then session data may not be persisted to disk.

Comment: we use `app.quit()` but as session cookies are set way before that, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can persist cookies setting the `session` and a `expirationDate`

This example was made on Angularjs

```
var session = require('electron').remote.session;
var ses = session.fromPartition('persist:name');

this.put = function (data, name) {
        var expiration = new Date();
        var hour = expiration.getHours();
        hour = hour + 6;
        expiration.setHours(hour);
        ses.cookies.set({
            url: BaseURL,
            name: name,
            value: data,
            session: true,
            expirationDate: expiration.getTime()
        }, function (error) {
            /*console.log(error);*/
        });
    };
```

PD: A problem that i had was if i didn't persist them, after a fews reloads my cookies get lost. So in this example i'd persist them 6 hours

Comment: how do i access the all of the sessions from the main renderer?? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading an external webpage, you should be using Electrons [`<webview>` tag](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md) to disable nodeintegration and for other security reasons. Using a webview will give you easy access to the [`Partition` attribute](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#partition) which can be set to persist (ex: `persist:mypage`). You can also set the partition attribute on an Electron window if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was loading an external webpage and the configuration below worked for me. By default the webpage is configured to use "session cookie" and thats why I change it to "persistent cookie" with expiration date of 2 weeks:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const util = require('util')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      partition: 'persist:infragistics'
    },
    icon: __dirname + '/assets/favicon.ico',
    show:false
  })



  let cookies = mainWindow.webContents.session.cookies;
  cookies.on('changed', function(event, cookie, cause, removed) {
    if (cookie.session && !removed) {
      let url = util.format('%s://%s%s', (!cookie.httpOnly && cookie.secure) ? 'https' : 'http', cookie.domain, cookie.path);
      console.log('url', url);
      cookies.set({
        url: url,
        name: cookie.name,
        value: cookie.value,
        domain: cookie.domain,
        path: cookie.path,
        secure: cookie.secure,
        httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
        expirationDate: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 14)
      }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          log.error('Error trying to persist cookie', err, cookie);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Note: Its important to ensure that you've set the ["partition" webPreferences property as well](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag#partition).

> A String that sets the session used by the page. If partition starts with persist:, the page will use a persistent session available to all pages in the app with the same partition. if there is no persist: prefix, the page will use an in-memory session

[Origin source](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9995).